# The [Spice] tag is being used for multiple things

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I know to be careful now when I pick on tags, but this [spice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spice) tag is being used for multiple things. I was going to ask a question about SPICE, the remote computing solution. Then, I saw people were using the tag for PySpice, Ngspice, and who knows what else. The problem is there are only a couple of questions with PySpice and Ngspice. So, they can’t have their own tags. What would be the best thing to do in this situation? [Some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380346/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-windows-inside-a-guest-os-w) have to do with using SPICE that shouldn't even be on SO!

Comment: There are numerous software systems called SPICE, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE & https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/spiceconcept.html

Comment: @PM2Ring But shouldn't tags be for just one thing? I mean for that you could make spice and nasa-spice for example

Comment: Yes, tags *should* be for one thing. I was just pointing out that the term spice is  problematic because several different things have used that name for decades.

Comment: Another one is [spacecraft planet instrument C-matrix ("camera matrix") events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE_(observation_geometry_system)). [Observed on](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54972/difference-in-results-between-jpl-horizons-and-cspice-rust-spice#comment124250_54972) *Astronomy*.

Comment: Considering there are only 11 questions, it should be easy enough to disambiguate those that *are* on topic and VTC (and delete) those that aren't.

Comment: Also, assuming you know something about at least on of these Spice things, strongly recommend create both a usage guidanxe and wiki for the tag(s) created.

Comment: @ThomA Yes, I submitted a description and wiki for [tag:spice] to be about the SPICE remote computing solution, it just hasn't been approved yet. I think that is the best fit for this tag as most of the questions are about that. Maybe Ngspice and PySpice questions should go in [tag:spice-circuits]. The rest should just be VTC. Especially if they aren't even about development

Comment: [[tag:spice]] should *go*; make a new tag that's not ambiguous. People don't (can't) read, it's "hard"; it takes up vital seconds of their day that they need *us* to use to get them the answer they *need*.

Comment: @ThomA Okay, how about [[tag:spice-remote-access]] and the rest go in [[tag:spice-circuits]]?

Comment: Actually, I've noticed there are [[tag:pspice]] and [[tag:pyspice]] tags. Should we make one for ngspice also or merge all the tags and create [[tag:spice-circuit-simulator]]? I say merge all them, because there are only a couple questions asked about them a year

Comment: I just found out PySpice just interfaces to Ngspice. Pspice, PySpice, and Ngspice are all related

Comment: The tag [[tag:pyspice]] was created today, @AnstonSorensen , and is from a user (moderator) changing the tag on some questions with the tag [[tag:spice]] to [[tag:pyspice]].

Comment: That still leaves [[tag:pspice]] and [[tag:spice]] should be removed from a couple of questions. The one question about usage still hasn't been closed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256446/discussion-between-anston-sorensen-and-thom-a).

Comment: The question about spice is listed under hot meta questions. Seems appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After cleaning the small remaining questions in the tag, I renamed the tag to [ngspice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngspice) (seems to be coding related, so on-topic). I did **not** synonym, as spice seems to be a broad topic. If it is ever recreated, we can consider a tag block at that time.

Comment: So then you just got rid of the questions that had to do with SPICE, the remote computing solution?

Comment: @AnstonSorensen There were only 5 questions when I saw it this morning. 3 needed closure/removal for being off-topic. I moved the two remaining ngspice questions into a more specific tag. I saw no generic SPICE questions, nor have I precluded there being a tag for it. I just agree there should be a more specific tag

Comment: I wonder who had 2000 reputation to create the tag in the first place. It seems like they would know better. Also, do you have the power to get rid of my tag description submission for the tag which is now [[tag:ngspice]]?

Comment: Excerpt rejected. Can submit another

Comment: Awesome, thank you